# How do I modify a function to return true if the given decimal is even when it is rounded to an integer and false otherwise?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Javascript exercise. I am trying to modify a function to return true when the given decimal is rounded to an even number and false when it is not.

So far I have

```
function isRoundedNumberEven(decimal){

}
console.log(isRoundedNumberEven(2.2), '<-- should be true');
console.log(isRoundedNumberEven(2.8), '<-- should be false');
```

Comment: Is this the entirety of your code? You haven't really made any attempt at all to solve the question you're asking. Consider making an attempt or doing some research to lead yourself to a *specific* question, as its current form is much too broad.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc., and give it a try.** *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the specific problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Math.round(decimal)%2==0 but yes please try yourslef first

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Why encourage or justify poor questions with answers?

Comment: sry I coudlnt help myself :(

Answer (score 3):

You have described two steps.

1. Round the number. This is easily achieved with [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)
2. Determine if it's even or odd. The easiest way to determine this is to divide by 2 and check the remainder. If the remainder is zero, then the number is even. Otherwise, it is odd.

   The way you do this is using the [modulo operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) - in this case, `roundedNumber % 2` would give you the remainder when dividing by 2.

   You just need to check if this remainder is `0` or `1`, and since you want to "return `true` if the number is even," then the easy way is `return roundedNumber % 2 === 0;`

I've provided the tools. Over to you now to assemble them in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

There are two key functions you need here: Math.round(decimal) and the modulo function: "%".

The first will round a decimal value.  So, Math.round(2.2) == 2, and Math.round(2.8) == 3.

The second will find the remainder after whole-number division of a number.  So, 2%2 == 0, and 3%2 == 1.

Hence, the contents of your function should be:

```
return Math.round(decimal) % 2 === 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isRoundedNumberEven(decimal){
    if((Math.round(decimal)%2) == 0) {
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should round first.  Using modulo on a float can result in floating-point errors.

Also, you can just return (decimal % 2) === 0; the if statement is redundant.